# Unable to re-open DSP device /dev/dsp: Permission denied

Tags: linux, open-source, audio, asterisk

So I downloaded the source for Asterisk last night and attempted to compile it. Everything seemed to run smoothly and no errors were apparent during the install process. I connected 2 IP phones to the server over the network and they registered fine. My problem comes afterwards:

after attempting to call from the console to one of the IP phones as a test, I got the following error

```
WARNING[9211]: chan_oss.c:485 setformat: Unable to re-open DSP device /dev/dsp: Permission denied
```

I've tried searching through all the different asterisk forums out there, but nothing seems to come up on this issue, and neither do my books.

I don't know if I did something wrong during compilation or what...

anyone got an idea?

---

switching to ALSA produced this error:

```
ERROR[10173]: chan_alsa.c:456 alsa_read: Read error: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

edit: And crashes Asterisk...

oddly enough, no other program are running that utilize sound, so I haven't the foggiest idea why it is happening!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much trial and error I found the issue: Asterisk 1.6 does not play nicely with Ubuntu.

I originally made the mistake of installing using the default Ubuntu apt-get repos', which are almost always outdated by 1-2 versions. I updated my repositories with the Asterisk ones and installed version 1.8 and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly want to be using `chan_alsa` not `chan_oss` unless your system is very old. The OSS sound system is very old now and modern systems normally use ALSA sound instead.

Comment: I switched it over to ALSA, however it gave me the following error:

`ERROR[10173]: chan_alsa.c:456 alsa_read: Read error: Resource temporarily unavailable`